# How to execute tests in TeamCity one by one

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nunit, teamcity

I have 17 tests executed in one job. 3-4 tests randomly fail each execution with a Timeout exception. It happens because they all are started at once and all don't get enough time/power to execute entirely.

How can I make sure each test is executed one by one?

Comment: Hi! TeamCity has no control over how your tests are executed and in which order. You should take a look at your selenium config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The first option** you can enable the 'Parallel tests' feature if you have TeamCity 2022.04+.
Read here more: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/parallel-tests.html

**The second option** is to handle parallel execution through NUNit itself. You can do that by adding a parameter

```
[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(5)]
```

in the Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs class (which is autogenerated)